# Указатель на структуру

Tags: структуры, c, указатели

Хочу получить указатель `root` на структуру

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>

struct books 
{
    float price;
    char Name[20];
    char NameofAuther[20];
};

struct books *root;

root = (books *)malloc(sizeof(books));

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%f", root->price);
    scanf("%s", root->Name);
    scanf("%s", root->NameofAuther);
    printf("\n%s of %s by %f", root->Name, root->NameofAuther, root->price);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> 'root' does not name a type

Почему?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это с. Здесь нужно явно писать слово struct всегда либо объявлять тип.

```
root = (struct books *)malloc(sizeof(struct books));
```

Либо делают так:

```
typedef struct _books 
{ 
    //.... 
} books;

books * root;
root = (books *)malloc(sizeof(books));
```